# How to completely deallocate or free all memory assigned in a linked list of struct

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

Stumbling in a small issue. Have tried most of ideas shared in stackoverflow for similar questions. I am expecting that the allocated space for the struct (8 bytes) is freed as well. A small snippet of what I am trying to achieve. In `struct person *p = NULL;` 8 bytes are allocated. Can I free this space as well ? Note the `free(&p)` is returning error Segmentation fault

```
// Online C compiler to run C program online
#include <stdio.h>

struct person {
    int age;
    char name[36];
    char surname[36];
    struct person *next;
};

struct person *init(struct person *p, int value, char name[36]) {
    struct person *newNode = (struct person *)malloc(sizeof(struct person));
    
    newNode->age = value;
    strncpy(newNode->name, name, 36);
    newNode->next = NULL;

    return newNode;
}

struct person *freeNode(struct person **p) {
    free(p);
    return p;
}

int main() {
    struct person *p = NULL;
    printf("Size %d \n", sizeof(p));
    p = init(p, 10, "joe");
    p = freeNode(p);
    printf("Size %d \n", sizeof(p));

    // Should free up all space and allocated space =0 (or less than 8)
    return 0;
}
```

UPDATED after your sound comments

What is actually the difference between:

a) Destroys an existing Mixed Stack and relinquishes associated memory resources.

b) Removes all elements from the Mixed Stack, resetting its
state to empty.

Comment: What's the point of returning the freed node?

Comment: Are you very sure about `p->name[36] ="hh";` ? There are several compiler warnings from this code. This one is *'=': 'char' differs in levels of indirection from 'char [3]'* You also break the array bound.

Comment: You can only free something that was allocate with `malloc()`. `p` is a local variable, `&p` is not a pointer to allocated memory

Comment: This shouldn't even compile. `init()` expects a `person*` argument, but `&p` is `person**`.

Comment: You have a number of problems in this code. You have to use `strcpy()` to copy strings, not assignment. You're passing the wrong pointer types to functions. You're never calling `malloc()` to allocate memory. You need to go back to your textbook or tutorial and reread the sections on dynamic memory allocation and freeing.

Comment: From the question title: by calling `free` on every pointer that was obtained from `malloc`, `strdup` etc, in the reverse sequence.

Comment: _In `struct person* p = NULL;` 8 bytes are allocated_. True, but those 8 bytes are allocated in _automatic storage_ (on a stack for all the implementations I've ever used), and that automatic storage will get cleaned up when `p` goes out of scope (when you hit the `}`). The memory that `p` _points_ to is what you have to manage with `malloc` and `free`. You haven't `malloc`ed anything, so there's nothing to `free`.

Comment: Reading your prompt comments am understanding more about the problems I am facing. Am very new to C. Came from C# :(

Comment: and you _must_ `malloc` something before doing things like `p->`. That `->` does a dereference, and since `p` doesn't point to any valid memory, `->` invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @FunMatters You could look at [this](https://godbolt.org/z/rzz4ffn3q) for inspiration